# Ruby: Split string but keep multiple whitespace

Tags: ruby

I just started doing Ruby today and I've been trying to use the split function. I want to keep the normal functionality of split but ensure that it only works for a single white space only. So if I have "Hello, I like   Apples", I want the resulting array to be ["Hello,","I","like"," ","Apples]

Thanks for the help

Comment: `str.split(' ')` and `str.split(/\s/)` will do that. The former splits on a single space; the latter on a single whitespace character (space, tab, form feed and so on.) Note your string appears to contain only a single space between "like" and "Apples". If so, you won't get `","` in the array that is returned.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I thought so but not it's not doing it.

Comment: @CarySwoveland the first still didn't work, but the second did thank you very much. I appreciate the help.

Comment: @CarySwoveland please use answers instead of comments for answering questions.